# using vba in excel to determinine minimum value from array of named ranges

Tags: excel, vba, min, named-ranges

I have a spread sheet with multiple dynamic named ranges such as HR_B1, to HR_B10 etc.

I am trying to create a function that will find the minimum value from whichever ranges are inserted into the function, i.e. the user function will input two values into the function say 3 and 6 and it will find the minimum value over ranges HR_B3 to HR_B6.

I have created a array and for loop that stores the names of the named ranges in the array.

However I cannot get the WorksheetFunction.Min code to read the contents of the array as named ranges and output the min value.

My code is:

```
Public Function HR_Min_Range(minval As Integer, maxval As Integer) As Variant

Dim fullrange() As Variant
Dim total_birds As Integer
Dim i As Long

total_birds = (maxval - minval)

ReDim fullrange(total_birds)

For i = 0 To total_birds

fullrange(i) = "HR_B" & (i + minval)
Next i

HR_Min_Range = WorksheetFunction.Min(Sheets("HR_Depths").Range(fullrange))

End Function
```

Comment: "I cannot get the WorksheetFunction.Min" why? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Try it as,

```
Option Explicit

Public Function HR_Min_Range(minval As Integer, maxval As Integer) As Variant

   Dim i As Long


    HR_Min_Range = Worksheets("HR_Depths").Range("HR_B" & minval).Cells(1)

    For i = minval To maxval
        HR_Min_Range = Application.Min(HR_Min_Range, Worksheets("HR_Depths").Range("HR_B" & i))
    Next i

End Function
```

Comment: I think I got Jeeped's code. Within the loop the application.min is adding a new argument to be used for each named range, so if there are 5 named ranges, it runs application.min with 5 arguments. is that correct?

Comment: Yes, given your example this would find the minimum values from named ranges HR_B3, HR_B4, HR_B5 and HR_B6.

Comment: I believe I understand now. There are only ever two arguments in the application.min, the first is fixed and the second increases with each loop by adding an extra named range to the overall area the application.min is looking at.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is like this:

```
Worksheetfunction.min([named])
```

or

```
WorksheetFunction.min(activesheet.range("named"))
```

or

```
WorksheetFunction.min(tabelle1.Range("named"))
```

or

```
Worksheetfunction.Min(worksheets("Tabelle1").range("named"))
```

or

```
Worksheetfunction.Min(tabelle1.[named])
```

or

```
Worksheetfunction.Min(worksheets("Tabelle1").[named])
```

Feel free to pick anything :) That's in case that the WorkSheet is with caption and code name `Tabelle1` and the named range is named `named`.

---

In you case, you are not putting `fullrange` in parenthesis or in `[`. Any of these two options should work.

Comment: Hi Jeeped,
Your code works but I am not sure how.
Could you explain what is going on in the loop?
Thanks

Comment: @Timm - jeeped's answer is above.